# Progress of dataOutputStream.readFully

Tags: java, android, dataoutputstream

I'm receiving a file using dataInputStream.readFully, so 
i'd like to show the progress of the transmision.
Is it possible to know the progress of readFully method?
Thank you.

Comment: No. To track progress, you need to do what it does. Look at the source: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/DataInputStream.java#l172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the whole point is that it's a single call to make it simpler to read.

If you want to read more gradually (e.g. to update a progress bar) you can just read a chunk at a time with `InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)` in a loop until you've read all the data. For example:

```
byte[] data = new byte[bytesToRead];
int offset = 0;
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = stream.read(data, offset, data.length - offset)) > -1) {
    offset += bytesRead;
    // Update progress indicator
}
```

This is just like the [JDK 8 code for `readFully`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/DataInputStream.java#l172), but with progress indication in the loop.

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, the point being that looping yourself allows the OP to update a progress indicator.

Comment: @Andreas: I see. Done.

Comment: Thank you so much!, this is so useful